# How does this snippet of GCNotification work? CLR via C#

Tags: c#

I'm reading CLR via C# now. In chapter 21 The Managed Heap and Garbage Collection, it shows a class that can raise an event when gc occurs. I only have some vague concept about the function of the class, but I can't understand how exactly the class work and how can I use it and how it interact with the GenObject class?
I've finished the Event Chapter.

```
public static class GCNotification
    {
        private static Action<Int32> s_gcDone = null;

        public static event Action<Int32> GCDone
        {
            add
            {
                if (s_gcDone == null)
                {
                    new GenObject(0);
                    new GenObject(2);
                }
                s_gcDone += value;
            }
            remove { s_gcDone -= value; }
        }

        private sealed class GenObject
        {
            private readonly Int32 m_generation;

            public GenObject(Int32 generation)
            {
                m_generation = generation;
            }

            //Finalize 方法
            ~GenObject()
            {
                if (GC.GetGeneration(this) >= m_generation)
                {
                    Action<Int32> temp = Volatile.Read(ref s_gcDone);
                    if (temp != null)
                    {
                        temp(m_generation);
                    }
                }

                if ((s_gcDone != null) &&
                    !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload() &&
                    !Environment.HasShutdownStarted)
                {

                    if (m_generation == 0)
                    {
                        new GenObject(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //放过对象
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't interact with `GenObjects` - as you can see, they are not stored anywhere, so they immediately become eligible for GC and their finalization process is used to signal the `GCDone` event. Based on my knowledge, this does not necessarily report GC collections but rather when Finalizer thread processes the specific objects which may or may not happen in relation to GC collections.

Comment: The book doesn't explain it?